# BLAS DGEMM: Can I pass C as A or B?

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas

I want to perform a string of matrix multiplies, and would prefer not allocate a fresh matrix if I can avoid it. For example, I want to compute C = C * B (so I pass in C as `A` and `C`)

Can I do this (due to `dgemm` having marked both `A` and `B` as `in` variables)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can never do this and it has nothing to do with the BLAS implementation. See

[Is it safe to pass GEMV the same output- as input vector to achieve a destructive matrix application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924948/is-it-safe-to-pass-gemv-the-same-output-as-input-vector-to-achieve-a-destructiv/9925720#9925720)

Answer (score 4):

None of the BLAS implementations I have even used had a dgemm which could work in-place.